# XNA UI hangs while using WCF remotely

Tags: wcf, azure, xna

I have an XNA client which communicates with a WCF service to operate.
The XNA application is actually a multiplayer pokergame.
When I run the WCF service locally, everything works well.

However, I lately deployed my WCF service into Azure. Now when I launch the client,
it starts OK, buttons are responsive and clickable.
The same is when I launch another client, and there is now an option to start a game 
(as there are 2 players).

Again, the StartGame button is clickable for both clients. 
However, once the game commences, the UI hangs and becomes unresponsive.

I can't reproduce this locally. This only happens while using the Azure service.
Note I'm not using any callbacks from the server back to the client, my client continuously polls the server and operates according that information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Problem was I had another service function being called continuously, not on a new thread. While executing locally, traffic was fast enough to overcome this.
However, running remotely caused application to hang due to the synchronous calls.